# Horizontal list view background

Tags: android, background, horizontallist

I got a problem regarding a small application where i am using Custom horizontal list view i have followed the below link for creating the horizontal list view.

And xml layout is like this..

```
 <com.example.HorizontalListView
      android:id="@+id/listview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
      android:divider="@color/Black"
       >
  </com.example.HorizontalListView>
```

But the problem is, **i cannot change the background for the horizontal list view**,could anybody help me ..@thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the background *dynamically.*

Please click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) for APIs for `View` from Android Developer Reference page. Keep in mind that below three methods can be used to add backgrounds to the `View` object:

```
public void setBackground (Drawable background);
public void setBackgroundColor (int color);
public void setBackgroundResource (int resid);
```

**onCreate:**

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);  

    HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);  
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);  

}
```

**BaseAdapter:**

```
private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {  

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);  
        retval.setBackgroundResource(R.id.my_background); // add this line

        return retval;  
    }  

};
```

Comment: @thanks for your quick response..i have tried that too but its not working!!the image is displaying below the view

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. I'm also playing around with HorizontalListView. First you need to add this line within the `<LinearLayout>` tag of `viewitem.xml`:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Then do this in `listviewdemo.xml`:

```
<com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_you_want"
/>
```

If you did this correctly you'll see the background showing through the HorizontalListView. The background stretches across the entire screen and it makes sense because the HorizontalListView also spans the entire screen as well.

Hope this helps.